# Should we contract the [expand] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

A [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4768324) came my way that proposed adding the wiki summary for [expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expand).

There are <strike>580</strike> 581 questions tagged such which do not really appear to be related in any manner:

- [How to expand the `Classname/staticField` macro syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407616/how-to-expand-the-classname-staticfield-macro-syntax)
- [Hiding group indicator in Expandable List view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339482/hiding-group-indicator-in-expandable-list-view)
- [html body extends after make element a negative position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214521/html-body-extends-after-make-element-a-negative-position)
- [Expand a Time Series to a specific number of periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616703/expand-a-time-series-to-a-specific-number-of-periods)
- [Python: print tuple gives empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579238/python-print-tuple-gives-empty-string)
- [Bug ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514015/bug-expandablelistview)
- [Expanding Date Class in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475182/expanding-date-class-in-ruby)

Does this tag serve any purpose?  If not, could we get rid of it?

Comment: I don't know about the tag, but the 2 people who tried to approve that suggested edit should be banned.

Comment: @Wooble I observed that too.  There are too many of such _reviewers_.  Nobody would like to ban half the community.

Comment: I'd totally like to ban half the community from approving edits. This will be my entire campaign strategy if I ever run for moderator again.

Comment: @Wooble If you declare that publicly, majority won't vote for you anyways.

Comment: @wooble: The meta-participating part might have a majority voting for him though... Hope springs eternal

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd be more than happy if that is the case.

Comment: Expand has only 2 followers, a long string of single answer top answerer, we can start.

Comment: @Braiam Is manual cleanup the only way?

Comment: @devnull Yes, manual cleanup is the only way

Answer (score 13):

You *expand* what, exactly? You normally expand *something*, right? Hence you should be using the something as tag, no?

In other words, let it burn.

Answer (score 3):

Time has passed, almost a decade, and [expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expand) now has over 1k questions with [the same issues as noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360834/11810933) for [expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expansion).

With only 13 upvotes here, that's not enough for a burnination, but in light of the additional (albeit just over the margin) votes on the [expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expansion) burninate-request, perhaps it would make sense to combine them, as I noted there?

Note that [expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expand) at least had someone edit in usage-guidance into its wiki, but it seems that a tag rename would have been better for that purpose.  Perhaps something like a general-purpose `ui-element-expansion` (suggestions welcome)?  Perhaps 40-50% of the questions (that I skimmed, at least) in the [expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expand) tag do seem to match that tag-wiki-guidance.  Being able to retag these with a more descriptive tag name could make the overall cleanup process easier.

Answer (score 0):

I asked in the past a somewhat similar question about a tag / edit where I also though that makes no sense (iirc it was about someone adding tag descriptions for a non-used tag).

The answer I got went along the lines "reviewers should only check if the review itself makes sense (e.g. spelling, language, no obscenity)" while the question if the tag itself makes sense and should (not) exist is out of scope.

So I guess that warrants a larger discussion.

- should verbs be allowed as tags at all (e.g. 'save' or 'load' would be bad, while 'load_indicator' could be good)
- how can bad tags be flagged / proposed for closing?
- should tags that no one is using (e.g. < 50 posts tagged ) be allowed to have a description at all?

Comment: I think that you've got it wrong.  The question was not about whether an edit needs to be approved or not, it was about whether the mentioned tag makes any sense.

Comment: @devnull I got that. I just said that in the past I was told that a reviewer was not supposed to judge if a tag makes sense. And I do not think having all those tags be treated in questions on meta makes a lot of sense too.

Comment: If you're reviewing a tag wiki edit, you definitely need to review the tag as well. Your task is to ensure that the proposed tag wiki content matches the tag usage. If the tag doesn't make sense, then the tag wiki cannot possibly make sense (unless it says “do not use this tag”, which is only useful for tags that require a mass cleanup effort). Most such tag wikis can be rejected as “not helpful” anyway, but if someone creates good a tag wiki for a useless tag, you should still go and remove the tag, and reject the suggested edit with a custom message.

Comment: The ideal time to create a tag wiki is when someone is using the tag, i.e. when the first post with that tag appears. Every tag has to start somewhere. There's no sense in withholding a definition until the tag has a lot of uses.