# We've seen too much [expansion]!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expansion) tag has no usage guidance and it seems it is used differently on every single question.

I'm only asking because [a question was just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868782/angular-material-nested-expansion-panels-spill-over-when-closed) with this tag and was going to suggest and edit to remove it as it made no sense.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't have a singular meaning. I see several questions posted with different meanings assigned to it, e.g. expanding UI elements, filenames, containers and more. It might qualify for a [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info)

Comment: It is relevant to [bash], automatic parameter expansion causes headaches.  And it is official terminology for [android] apk expansion files.  And relevant in [c], macro preprocessor expansion causes surprises.  Just a little soldier tag that adds a detail to the primary tag(s), we favor questions having more than one tag.

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting, I didn't know that. But should it be used in that question just because an HTML element has a name `mat-expansion-panel`?

Comment: SO questioners always need lots of help turning their question into something that is useful to programmers for years to come.   Tagging their question properly is just one of them.

Comment: @HansPassant That sounds like too many meanings for 1 tag. We generally try to keep it to 1 meaning.

Comment: Hmm, of, say, [c][macro][expansion] there is one tag that has entirely too many meanings, producing over a quarter of a million questions.  The meaning of the others are exact.

Comment: "Could you expand on the purpose of the `expansion` tag?"

Comment: It is for posts that simply expand the site without providing any useful Q&A :)

Comment: @HansPassant [tag:bash] experts likely have enough familiarity with the topic that a tag for filtering isn't needed. Macro expansion exists in many languages, and the language tag is enough in those cases. Tags are not for adding minute details; tags are for broad filtering purposes. APK Expansion Files might be worth being a tag in its own right; I don't know enough about the technology to know.

Comment: Are you a [bash] expert?  Your profile suggests you are not, but it isn't always obvious.  Squirrely thing about users that ask questions about [bash] assume they'll find a user that knows the [expansion] intricacies when they add that tag.  If they don't then it is pretty unlikely their answer is going to be helpful.  Seems like the kind of SO users that demand less ambiguous tags are the ones that don't know squat about the subject.  What is the point of that?  They'll never post a useful answer.  I always assumed that is what the site is all about.  But it might be all about review today.

Comment: @HansPassant What information is communicated by [tag:expansion] that wouldn't be achievable with a half decent title? And why do you expect a user who doesn't write a half decent title to find this tag and figure out they should use it? And why do you assume that a user who would write a bad answer to a wilfcard expansion question would not write the answer just because the tag is there? No, I don't know everything about bash expansion. But I do know it's an integral part of bash, and if I post a well researched question with a decent MVCE, I expect help figuring out the cause.

Comment: @HansPassant Given that there are only 307 questions that even have the tag and only 80 of them are tagged with [tag:bash] (out of over 94,000 bash questions), I'm confident that most of the questions related to wildcard resolution and string interpolation don't even have [tag:expansion]. So your point is utterly moot since it's not used in the way you suggest it should be. And even *within* [tag:bash], it's not clear what it means; it could mean wildcard resolution of file paths or string interpolation or decompressing files.

Comment: [tag:expansion] is a classical example of a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). That it requires other tags as "context" is proof enough.

Answer (score 11):

**Kill it with fire.**

It's used for all sorts of clearly unrelated meanings even just at a glance:

- Expanding/collapsing UI elements: [Angular Material : nested expansion panels spill-over when closed.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47868782/1394393), [Row Details for Datatable by Bootsfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44020476/1394393)
- Macro resolution: [Inspecting code with Scalac (v12.2.3) - error: macro annotation could not be expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47542805/1394393), [Macros expansion using ## operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47206932/1394393)
- Mechanisms for delivering companion data: [Showing image with Picasso custom Downloaded uses a lot of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47407624/1394393) (references [APK expansion files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html))
- Wildcard resolution: [Bash filename expansion identifies items in file tree, called command not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47394325/1394393), [expand wildcards in string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44921784/1394393)
- String interpolation: ["$()" or `` is not properly expanding the linux command in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43169453/1394393)
- Some kind of inheritance scheme: [C# Static Class and Static Constructor for API system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46470905/1394393)
- Resource increases in parallel computing: [adding new DC just for Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43792192/1394393)
- Infinite series representations of mathematical functions: [How to obtain a taylor series of sine in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42980590/1394393)

And much, much more.

An argument that the tag provides some additional clarity within the context of other tags has been made. However, this argument is invalid because:

- It's not clear even in the context of particular technologies. I have examples of [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) questions above using it to refer to both string interpolation and wildcard resolution of file paths. There are a wide variety of UI elements that expand and collapse.
- It's barely used. Only 307 questions are tagged with it. Since askers aren't using it on their questions hardly at all, they either don't think the clarification is necessary or didn't find the tag to use, and it is almost never there for an answerer to see for any additional clarity.
- Even if it were used, the trivial details it provides are easily clarified with a decent title. In fact, two or three words used in the title can easily provide vastly *more* clarity than this tag can.

The tag is hopelessly vague, isn't used even remotely consistently, could never stand anywhere near alone, and has no field of expertise related to it. It's a poster child for burination. Please convert your question to a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request).

If there are any meaningful tags that could be associated with some of the various meanings, they should be created with much more specific names.

Answer (score 2):

To repeat @jpmc26's position from 6 years ago:

> **Kill it with fire.**

I cannot find a single question where the use of [expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expansion) *improves* the clarity or searchability.  On the contrary, it makes the tags on these posts more ambiguous, when there are typically far better tags that could have been used to improve the questions' searchability.

It continues to be used and is now up to 436 undeleted questions on wildly varying topics.

For most of the usages below (other than the first two, highly obvious ones) I've attempted to provide an example, but note that most of these uses have been seen many times:

- Variable expansion questions are covered by [variable-expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-expansion)
- Glob/Wildcard expansion is implicitly already covered by the use of the tags [glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glob) and [wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildcard)
- [Splitting a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23157613/11810933) should be [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/split) according to that tags usage-guidance
- [APK expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10710922/11810933) is, AFAICT, already covered by [apk-expansion-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk-expansion-files).  Side-note that [expansion-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expansion-files) should be made a synonym of [apk-expansion-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk-expansion-files).
- [Image resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15903188/11810933) (covered by [image-resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-resizing))
- [Expanding widgets/UI-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76907450/11810933) have a number of related tags already that might could be merged into something more useful. Note: Typing *"expan"* into the [Tag Search](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) yields potential candidates.
- [General shell expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76842556/11810933) *might* warrant a new tag `shell-expansion`
- [Preprocessor/Macro expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76471817/11810933) is (probably?) already implicit in the use of [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) and [preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preprocessor).
- [An increase in storage use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76420197/11810933) is more appropriate in [diskspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diskspace) or related.
- [Splatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75873479/11810933) doesn't need [expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expansion) when it typically already has [splat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splat)

Can we borrow a match (a.k.a. a Moderator move this to [Stage 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/11810933))?

Answer (score 1):

Related, but separate enough that I'm adding it as another answer:

See: [Is there a good use for the [expand] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254161/11810933) with even *more* questions (over 1,100 at this point).

Should/could these efforts be combined?  Could a case be made for mass retagging all [expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expansion) questions as [expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expand) and then working on burninating them in one effort?